# Using Grsync to set up a backup job via GUI, can I see the rsync command it created?

Tags: command-line, gui, rsync, grsync

Is there a way to view the actual command that `grsync` ends up running?

The idea is to setup a backup job in `Grsync`, exactly as I want it with all the options, and subsequently use the command to have it run by `cron` for regular backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can! `Grsync` is actually a great GUI tool to generate `grsync` commands.

#### How to see the command you created via GUI in `Grsync`

1. Create your backup via GUI in `Grsync`
2. Once that is done, choose: File > Rsync command line

That's it. now the command you created via gui is displayed. Just copy it to use in `cron` or whatever procedure you use to make backups.

[image]

Comment: haha, I feel foolish for not seeing that. Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesS It took me a while as well in those days, but it is a great tool to generate the commands!